# Scatter plot points don't appear when run within R Markdown

Tags: r, plotly, r-markdown, scatter-plot

When I plot a scatter plot with plotly in R, the output differs significantly when I try to plot the same code in R Markdown.

1. Scatter plot in R
   [image: Scatter plot in R]
2. Scatter plot in Markdwon
   [image: Scatter plot in Markdown]

the code:

Given that there are more than 8,000 values, I can provide a plot using the first 20 values as an example.

```
structure(list(indice = 1:20, Media_Recomendacao = c(9, 7, 8, 
8, 7, 7, 9, 8, 0, 0, 9, 9, 6, 7, 4, 7, 8, 8, 9, 7), Media_CSAT = c(8.43, 
6.14, 7.5, 8, 6.79, 7.79, 6.93, 7.79, 5.64, 4.21, 9.29, 7.93, 
6.14, 6.29, 5.14, 6.86, 8, 7.71, 8.64, 7.21)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
fig <- 
plot_ly(
    data = dispersion, 
    x = ~Media_CSAT,
    y = ~Media_Recomendacao,
    type = 'scattergl',
    mode = "markers",
    marker = list(color = 'grey')) %>%
layout(
    xaxis = list(
        title = "Valor CSAT",
        tickmode = "array",
        tickvals = 1:10,
        ticktext = 1:10), 
    yaxis = list(title = "Recomendação",
        tickmode = "array",
        tickvals = 1:10,
        ticktext = 1:10)
  )

fig
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to fix this issue. I suspect that Markdown is plotting the mean of x and y instead.

Comment: Please provide sample data, perhaps `dput(head(dispersion,20))`, and a reduced markdown document to demonstrate the difference between console and rendered formats.

Comment: add sample data

Comment: That plots just fine for me on the console, and when I create a simple rmarkdown document myself, it plots there just fine as well. How are you calling `rmarkdown::render`? Please provide a simplified rmarkdown document that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: it works for me too! Are you sure about this Radupi?

Comment: i only have:
{r, comment=FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.align='center', warning=TRUE, echo = FALSE, warning=FALSE, width=10}

with the same code i use in R

Comment: In my experience most likely you are simply plotting different data, and mistakenly thinking that it is the same data. Rmarkdown knits into a clean environment, whereas you may be working interactively in a workspace; people can often get messed up like this with dynamic workspaces and running code fragments rather than entire end to end scripts in clean environment;

Comment: For example, lets say you run the markdown and it loads and plots data, only a few points. you think, "thats no good". interactively load the correct data containing more points, plot that, then not remember to update the markdown to reflect the necessary change that introduce more data into your active session; or something along those lines.

Comment: I just updated _my_ rmarkdown document to that chunk header and it still works. So ... _how are you calling `render`?_ Are you using a [parameterized rmarkdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html)? What is your yaml top matter? Do you have much text before/after that block? Some new questions: what versions of R, `knitr`, `rmarkdown`, and `plotly` do you have installed? What OS?

Comment: I am unable to solve this issue. How should I write the code in Markdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

````
---
title: A plot
params:
  data:
output: html_document
---


```{r, comment=FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.align='center', warning=TRUE, echo = FALSE, warning=FALSE, width=10}
plot_ly(
    data = params$data, 
    x = ~Media_CSAT,
    y = ~Media_Recomendacao,
    type = 'scattergl',
    mode = "markers",
    marker = list(color = 'grey')) %>%
layout(
    xaxis = list(
        title = "Valor CSAT",
        tickmode = "array",
        tickvals = 1:10,
        ticktext = 1:10), 
    yaxis = list(title = "Recomendação",
        tickmode = "array",
        tickvals = 1:10,
        ticktext = 1:10)
  )
```
````

```r
dispersion <- structure(list(indice = 1:20, Media_Recomendacao = c(9, 7, 8, 8, 7, 7, 9, 8, 0, 0, 9, 9, 6, 7, 4, 7, 8, 8, 9, 7), Media_CSAT = c(8.43, 6.14, 7.5, 8, 6.79, 7.79, 6.93, 7.79, 5.64, 4.21, 9.29, 7.93, 6.14, 6.29, 5.14, 6.86, 8, 7.71, 8.64, 7.21)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
rmarkdown::render("~/tmp/quux.Rmd", params=list(data=dispersion))
# processing file: quux.Rmd
#                                                                                                                                                
# output file: quux.knit.md
# /usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS quux.knit.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output quux.html --lua-filter /home/r2/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /home/r2/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --self-contained --variable bs3=TRUE --section-divs --template /home/r2/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable theme=bootstrap --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url=https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' --include-in-header /home/r2/tmp/rmarkdown-str6d0913f4c662d.html 
# Output created: quux.html
```

[image: rmarkdown with plotly]